# Add property to an existing object in twig

Tags: php, object, inheritance, twig, grav

I am about to build a [modular page](https://learn.getgrav.org/content/modular) theme in [grav](https://getgrav.org/) (which uses [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) as a template engine).

By default, a modular theme consists of at least two twig template files: one provides the page frame including the head and another one that provides the markup of a content module. Grav's [standard theme](https://github.com/getgrav/grav-theme-antimatter) provides examples of these templates:

1. [modular page frame example](https://github.com/getgrav/grav-theme-antimatter/blob/develop/templates/modular.html.twig)
2. [module example](https://github.com/getgrav/grav-theme-antimatter/blob/develop/templates/modular/text.html.twig)

As you can see, the module (example) does not have a `head` or `javascripts` block to add javascripts to the html head. (This wouldn't even be possible, as a typical modular page consists of multiple modules. So if two different modules would try to change the `javascripts` block the last one would overwrite the changes made by the first one which would lead to unintended results).

However, it happens that I need to add some javascript code to the head of my page from within a module. I thought about a solution and had the idea to add the javascript-code as a property to an object that exists "site wide", namely the [pages object](https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/theme-vars#pages-object).

This leads to my question:

*How can I add properties to an existing object **using the twig syntax**?*

Apart from that I would also like to know if you can think of any reasons why this solution could possibly not work. But if you help me with the syntax, I can also just give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating the state of an object shouldn't be done in a Twig template. The view should be outputting data that has been supplied to it.

> try to change the javascripts block the last one would overwrite the changes made by the first one which would lead to unintended results

See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658503/twig-append-content-to-block) for an explanation of how to have multiple blocks append content to a block rather than overwrite it. You can simply have a 'extra_scripts' block or something like that, then append any required javascript for a particular module to that block as per the described link. Essentially you need to use `{{ parent() }}` to ensure content is included from the parent

Comment: first of all: thanks for your answer. However, I am afraid this cannot be done appending a block using `{{ parent() }}`, because the block that should be appended doesn't come from the parent. I try to explain it with a sketch https://www.twiddla.com/xa84jm . But even if it would work, another (more important) problem is, that the module templates simply don't inherit from the page frame, so it is not even theoretically possible to inherit from the parent.